# Best way to define Client to be used with localhost vs domain

Tags: identityserver4

so I got my Identity Server project up and running, and am setting up my project to publish. Now, when I define my client in the config for IS4, I suppose I will have to set my redirect urls to my publish domain, something like this:

```
new Client{
    ...
    RedirectUris = { "localhost:5002/signin-oidc", "myclient.com/signin-oidc" }
    ...
}
```

Is including the localhost and domain the right way to do this?

I am thinking it would be ok since an attacker would have to have my client secret in order to login. Or is it better to set up two separate clients (eg. 'client' and 'client_local'), and request the appropriate client at startup?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1) **Use Configuration File**: You can store the clients in a JSON file and load them during startup. Use different JSON files for different environments.

Example. clients.Development.json for Development and clients.Production.json in Production environment; However, The clients will be In Memory Clients and any changes in clients configuration will require a reboot of your application.

2) **Use Persistent Storage:** Use a database server to store configuration and operational data. A local database for development and a database for production use.

See this [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html), The example uses Entity Framework for persistent storage but you're bound to Entity Framework or any ORM. You can opt to write your own Data Access Layer for IdentityServer. This will allow you to change client configurations without restarting your application as the data will be retrieved from a database.